# Pre render website pages built using StencilJS web components

Tags: web-component, prerender, stenciljs

We have a CMS based web site which uses web components built using StencilJS 0.x .
For our search requirements we need pre rendered DOM of our pages which contains the innerHTML as if it is rendered in browser!

Is there any way we can achieve this ?

I have tried NodeJS server which is based on  [Prerender](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) but no luck. It is giving me page html with my component tags but not the rendered DOM!

I know about Stencil's pre rendering support but that is for stencil based apps. My application is not Stencil app but it is using just some components.

Comment: Do the StencilJS components use Shadow DOM? Because Prerender.io can render Shadow DOM but we can't capture the Shadow DOM HTML since it doesn't get exported in the HTML.

Comment: Stencil has [built in support for prerendering](https://stenciljs.com/docs/prerendering), have you tried that?